# Can broadcastreceiver take full control?

Tags: android

I have the following question:

Is it possible to completely override a phone-function when receiving a BroadcastReceiver? For example, is it possible to receive sms and do not let the sms to appear in the notification area?

thanks

Comment: Depends on exactly what function you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible just define your BR like below code. make sure you call `abortBroadcast();` method from receiver so it wont allow to further call onReceives of other BRs.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"
              android:exported="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
             <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
             </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

but it wont guaranteed to work all the time as there may be other apps doing same and could have abortedBroadcast, so there may be chances even your onReceive wont be tringger.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes. It depends on what type of broadcast it is. Take a look through the [docs for `BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> There are two major classes of broadcasts that can be received:
>
> - Normal broadcasts (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.
> - Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

SMS happens to be an ordered broadcast, so in this case if you call [`abortBroadcast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29), other receivers with a lower [priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority) will not be called. This will only work if your priority is the highest though, which is not really possible to guarantee, but you can do a reasonable job by just setting a very high priority, perhaps [over 9000](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik) might be appropriate. Although the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY) do say to not use anything 1000 or over, this is to ensure that the system always gets to handle the broadcasts. In your case though, you really do want to stop the system from handling the broadcast.